# If A and B are both pathwise-connected, and the intersection of A and B is nonempty, show that A union B is pathwise-connected

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, path-connected

My thought process here was to use a theorem in our textbook that says that a subset A of R is pathwise-connected iff A is an interval. Therefore it suffices to show that A union B is an interval. Since A and B are both intervals and their intersection is nonempty, it should follow that A union B is an interval, but I do not know if I need more for this section of the proof to show that AuB is an interval. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use the definition of path-connectedness. Take a point in $A$ and take a path to a point in the intersection (which exists since the intersection is nonempty). Then, take another path from this same point in the intersection to a point in $B$. I'll leave it to you to formalize this idea rigorously.

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb R$ is pathwise-connected iff it is an interval; does your textbook really say $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are correct the textbook says for R, not R^n, I will update my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: You don’t need intervals: you just need the definition of *path*. Let $p\in A\cap B$, and let $x,y\in A\cup B$. There is a path $f$ from $x$ to $p$ in $A\cup B$ (why?), and there is a path $g$ from $p$ to $y$ in $A\cup B$ (again, why?). Now show how to combine $f$ and $g$ to get a path from $x$ to $y$ in $A\cup B$.

Comment: There is a path from x to p in A union B because A is pathwise connected and similarly for B? Do I need a composition in this instance?

Comment: @thomasbdc: Not quite: if $x\in A$, there is a path from $x$ to $p$ because $A$ is pathwise connected, and if $x\in B$, there is a path from $x$ to $p$ because $B$ is pathwise connected. The argument for $y$ similarly requires two cases. You don’t want a composition: you want to combine $f$ and $g$ in a single function $h$ that first takes you from $x$ to $p$ and then takes you from $p$ to $y$. This won’t be a composition; it’s more of a pasting together end to end.

Comment: I think I got it, using an h(x) = f(x) + g(x) - p so that h(a) = f(a) + g(a) - p = x + p - p = x and h(b) = f(b) + g(b) - p = p + y - p = y

Comment: @thomasbdc: That makes no sense for the usual definition of *path*: a path from $x$ to $p$ is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^n$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=p$. Do you have some different definition of a path?

Comment: we use [a,b] as the interval so that f(a) = x and f(b) = p and for g, g(a) = p and g(b) =y

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I think what you are talking about could be called a [path composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition)

Comment: Either way, thank you for the help, I think I figured it out with those hints!

Comment: I don't think the solution $h(x) = f(x) + g(x) - p$ would necessarily work unless $A \cup B$ is convex or something along those lines.  How would you know that the path $h$ stays entirely within $A \cup B$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler: You’re absolutely right; I wasn’t thinking.

Comment: @thomasbdc: My last comment was thoughtless: the path that you have in mind may not lie entirely in $A\cup B$. You really will have to use the more general approach: $$h(t)=\begin{cases}f(2t-a),&\text{if }a\le t\le\frac12(a+b)\\g(2t-b),&\text{if }\frac12(a+b)\le t\le b\,.\end{cases}$$ Now the first half of $h$ traverses $f$, and the second half traverses $g$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you for that. I will update my proof with this given h

Comment: @thomasbdc: You’re welcome; I apologize for my carelessness.